# Is there a way to start a command prompt with batch, then run multiple commands in that command window?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to do something along the lines of `start cmd.exe /k <commandOne> <commandTwo>`. Basically as the title says, I want to start a command prompt, then have multiple commands run in that command prompt. Is this possible? I haven't found any suitable answers yet, and I would appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need `start`. `cmd /k command1 & command2 & command3`.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: If the question is unclear, then you shouldn't have answered it until the poster made an edit to clarify what they're asking, and should have voted to close it as needing details or clarity.. The reason I posted a comment instead of an answer was for that very reason.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: When your answer starts with *Your question is unclear. I am not sure whether you want...So here's them all* and you write an answer that would cover 10 different questions being asked, you don't have a *pretty close idea* what the poster wants. The question is entirely unclear, and should have been closed until it was edited. In its current state, it contributes no value to the site, and answering it sets a bad precedent with this poster and others that they can ask vague, unclear questions and still get answers to them.

Comment: Isn't the point of executing a batch file to run multiple commands? So I am not understanding what you are having problems with.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear what you want, but I have a fairly good Idea. So here's a few different examples.

From cmd to run multiple commands from the same prompt, whether the the previous command completed successfully or not.

```
command1 & command2 & command3
```

Or conditional. In other words only run the next command if the previous completed successfully. (in other words command1 must exit with `%errorlevel% 0` before `command2` will start and so forth.

```
command1 && command2 && command3
```

Similar to above, but only the first command must complete successfully before the others can run, `command2` in this instance can fail and `command3` will still run.

```
command1 && command2 & command3
```

another conditional example, the code inside the block makes `command2` dependant on `command1` to complete, but `command3` will run regarless of the other two's failure.

```
(command1 && command2) & command3
```

To start a new `cmd` window and run the commands in it and closing the cmd when done.

```
start cmd /c command1 ^& command2 ^& command3
```

To start a new `cmd` window and run some command in it and others locally and keep the window open.

```
start cmd /k command1 & command2 & command3
```

Or run each command in parallel

```
command1 | command2 | command3
```

running commands and another batch file

```
command1 & call command2.cmd & command3
```

Or if you just wanted a straight forward batch file.

or start a command in a new window, wait for it to complete, then run another command locally and call a batch file.

```
start "" /wait command1 & command2 & call command3.cmd
```

run 2 commands and redirect both comamnds outputs to `nul`

```
(command1 & command2)>nul
```

same thing, but redirect `stderr` to `stdout` as well.

```
(command1 & command2)>nul >2&1
```

or redirect only one command to nul

```
command1 >nul >2&1 & command2
```

or just plain  `batch-file`

```
@echo off
Command1
Command2
Command3
pause
```

When getting to loops and other things it will become a bit more than just straight forward commands, but from what you asked, this should about cover it.